# How to bound inter-arrival times?

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I model a phenomenon such that events occur strictly in adherence to Poisson with mean T (no need for two events happening at the same time, events are independent, and all intervals are alike).

Now, based on this, I need to generate "time to next event" - so i take the help of exponential distribution and model inter arrival times, at mean = 1/T. To achieve this, I follow [Donald Knuth's](http://preshing.com/20111007/how-to-generate-random-timings-for-a-poisson-process/) algorithm to generate a uniform random number in [0,1) and pick corresponding x value representing next arrival.

This doesn't work for me well as I want my next arrival to be **strictly** within T (as is, P(X>T) = e^-1). So, I generate a uniform random number within [ 0, (1-(e^-1)) ) = [0,0.632) for example and pick corresponding arrivals and guarantee P(X>T) = 0.

**Questions**

**1.** Is there anything wrong with my approach?

**2.** Is there a more optimal approach to bound inter arrival times? Is there any other distribution that I should go after instead of Poisson/Exponential?

**3.** What're advantages and disadvantages of stubbing (i.e. I set inter arrival time to T if I get arrTime > T)?

Obviously, 36.8% (e^-1 %) values drawn from this distribution are exactly T, which is not that desirable, as resulting distribution appears less random to an external observer.

Thanks so much - I only started looking into Poisson/Exponential distributions recently so be gentle.

Comment: If it's a Poisson process, the inter-arrival times are not bounded.  Why do you want the next arrival time less than $T$?

Comment: I **must** satisfy arrTime <= T  requirement!

I can choose any distribution (of course my use case needs to adhere to its assumptions).

Comment: If you assume that the event must happen by time $T$ then you must have some sort of non-memoryless process going on, which will create a bias from one moment to the next. One way to define this process is to simply condition on the exponential variable lying in $[0,T]$, that is, to take a random variable with $P(Y \in [a,b])=\frac{P(X \in [a,b] \cap [0,T])}{P(X \in [0,T])}$ and in particular $P(Y \leq y)=\frac{P(X \leq \min \{ y,T \})}{P(X \leq T)}$. This is not exactly the same as your approach, in particular this r.v. is continuous, so $P(Y=T)=0$.

Comment: But it is not necessarily the correct approach, once you drop the memoryless assumption you open up the possibility of other modeling assumptions that lead to other distributions.

Comment: To see how it would arise in simulation, note that (assume $X$ has rate $1$ for simplicity) $P(Y \leq y)=\frac{\int_0^{\min \{ y,T \}} e^{-s} ds}{\int_0^T e^{-s} ds}=\frac{1-e^{-\min \{ y,T \}}}{1-e^{-T}}$. You then need to set that equal to a number $u \in (0,1)$ and solve the equation for $y$ in order to make a simulation. So $y=-\ln(-(-1+(1-e^{-T})u))=-\ln(1-u+e^{-T}u)$.

Comment: Thanks Ian .. I'm not quite sure how you arrived at y=−ln(−(−1+(1−e−T)u))=−ln(1−u+e−Tu), as we need to solve for min(y,T). Kindly clarify ...

Comment: actually I take that back. After 100K simulations, I see mean of the new distribution as ~1 & max << T ... so, yes I get what I need, except now the distribution is way left-skewed - quite undesirable.

Comment: @user2574529 You need to solve for $\min \{ y,T \}$ but you can see that this is an increasing function of $y$ and it is equal to $1$ exactly when $y=T$. Thus you really have $\frac{1-e^{-y}}{1-e^{-T}}$ for the CDF. So in fact you also have a PDF: it is $\frac{e^{-y}}{1-e^{-T}}$ for $y$ between $0$ and $T$ and zero otherwise. So the PDF is still decreasing with the same basic shape as the exponential distribution but it abruptly cuts off at $y=T$ (and is renormalized accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Ian. After a bit of thought (& simulation, see results below) your method actually normalizes CDF with P(X<=T, lambda=1/T) and has the exact same effect as my original approach. ** So, I'm back to my original questions.** Pls let me know if I should try any other distributions ( Renewal? ) or if this math has no issues given it violates Poisson's memoryless property.

There were slight changes needed on your math, primarily because Exponential "rate" corresponds to Poisson 1/"mean/lambda". Thus, P(Y<=y) = (1-exp(min(y,T))/(1-exp(-((1/T)*T)) = (1-exp(min(y,T))/(1-exp(-1)) (this is exactly same as normalizing otherwise [0,1) to [0,1-exp(-1)).

**CODE:**

%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd

import random

import numpy as np

import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def next(rate):

```
u = random.random()

K = (1-math.exp(-1))

rval = (-1/rate)*math.log(1-(K*u))


return (rval)
```

def truncNext(rate):

```
u = random.uniform(0,(1-math.exp(-1)))

rval = -math.log(1.0-u)/rate

return (rval)
```

n = [next(1/100.0) for x in np.arange(1e6)]

trunc_n = [truncNext(1/100.0) for x in np.arange(1e6)]

f = pd.DataFrame({'cond-Exp': n,
                  'trunc-Exp': trunc_n})

f.describe()

**RESULTS:**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmpKj.jpg)